# Sitecore package install never ends

Tags: sitecore

I got an interesting problem. When I install a Sitecore package the user interface never gets updated when the package is fully installed. The Sitecore package installation is hanging.

In the Sitecore logs I see:

```
ManagedPoolThread #18 11:36:00 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Portals/Default/{BEA47CD0-C3B3-4EFD-A781-997292620312}/nl/1/xml
ManagedPoolThread #18 11:36:00 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Portals/Default/foobar/{4E0129CF-1C03-4BC8-B049-7D641D46797C}/en/1/xml
ManagedPoolThread #18 11:36:00 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Portals/Default/foobar/{4E0129CF-1C03-4BC8-B049-7D641D46797C}/nl/1/xml
ManagedPoolThread #18 11:36:00 INFO  Installing of blob values has been finished. Installed: 3 Skipped: 0
ManagedPoolThread #18 11:36:00 INFO  Committing files.
ManagedPoolThread #11 11:36:00 INFO  Job started: WatchStatus
```

This indicates that everything is installed correctly but in Sitecore the loading bar is still running.
Does anybody know what can cause this because the logs are empty.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After a lot of research in Sitecore.Kernel.dll I found the solution.
After the "INFO Committing files." log entry there was another entry: "Job started: WatchStatus". This Job never ended.

The `ItemInstaller` is responsible for the "Installing item:" logs and the `BlobInstaller` is responsible for the "Installing of blob values has been finished" log.
In the `InstallPackageForm` class, the function `WatchForInstallationStatus()` is responsible for the "Job started: WatchStatus" logmessage. This function starts a new thread in which it checks the status of the package installation which is stored in the temp folder.
In my case, the IIS_IUSRS role did not have write rights on the temp folder. After I changed it, it worked.

This is what the log file should look like:

```
ManagedPoolThread #7 12:45:57 INFO  Committing files.
ManagedPoolThread #11 12:45:57 INFO  Job started: WatchStatus
ManagedPoolThread #7 12:45:57 INFO  Job ended: Install (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #11 12:45:58 INFO  Job ended: WatchStatus (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #8 12:45:58 INFO  Job started: InstallSecurity
ManagedPoolThread #8 12:45:58 INFO  Installing security from package: <package>
```

Comment: Had the same problem. After investigating the logs, it was because the installation had failed silently, and just kept on running in the UI.

Comment: The error in my logs was: PathTooLongException. No idea how to fix though.

Comment: @Bertvan In some cases the TEMP directory can end up being nested farther than 255 characters. It fails to read them in some windows environments

Answer (score 11):

After the default installation of 8.0 Update 4 you need to run mongo manually.

The easiest way is to install mongo by default and run it from command prompt as: mongod.exe --dbpath c:\example_of_my_mongo_database_dir

The best way is to install it as a windows service - http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/02/02/install-mongodb-as-a-windows-service-for-sitecore/

As soon as you do that - you'll be able to install the packages without any problem.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else that has this issue that might be in the same way that I had it. I had the exact same problem, but not quite with the same stack traces as defined above.

My problem was that I didn't have MongoDB installed/running, and that caused it to hang, throwing many errors in the logs. Doing a simple install and a couple setup commands with the pre-defined connection strings seemed to kick it into gear just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I have given write permissions to IIS_IUSRS for website folder on Inetpub.

Its bit strange as I already got full permissions to APPPooluser on website folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the Sitecore package zip never finishes installation:
There was a log entry entry: “Job started: WatchStatus”. This Job never ended.

The package is being stored in a temporary folder on my local machine, and instead of running under the NETWORK SERVICE account that the website uses, it runs with IIS_IUSRS role which did not have modify permissions. I granted modify permissions to this role and the package created as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `inetpub\wwwroot\newsxa[Your file]\Website\App_Config\Include` 
where you will find `Sitecore.Xdb.config in line 8`

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />
```

Just make it false

It will install after that.