# When Installing Sitecore unable to install Zip Packages Sitecore E-Commerce Services 2.2rev

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am new to sitecore development.I have installed Sitecore 8(using SQL Server) and after installing when I try to install zip packages (Sitecore E-Commerce Services 2.2 rev,Sitecore E-Commerce Order Manager 2.2 ,Active Commerce-SC80 3.2 rev).
I see a never ending "Installing package" message. Need Help.

Comment: Active Commerce fully supports SES 2.2 on Sitecore 8 and the installation should work fine. (source: I am the CTO of Active Commerce.)

Comment: Ranjit - Are you installing these one at a time? Are you installing SES first? Any additional information in your Sitecore logs which may be relevant? Need more information to help you.

Comment: Relevant / possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041253/sitecore-package-install-never-ends

Comment: @techphoria414 I started with SES.

Comment: @ranjitchoudhary I would recommend looking at the solutions in the question I linked above. Filesystem permissions, mongodb, etc.

Comment: @techphoria414 Thanks I am able to install SES2.2, and order manager but getting some error while installing active commerec. Please help, here is link I have wriiten question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305359/while-installing-active-commerce-sc80-3-2-i-get-an-error-unable-to-load-one-or

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes install packages do spin for ever depending on the speed of your machine.  While large packages are installed, I generally use a program like BareTail to monitor the Sitecore Log file, and highlight on the word "Installing Item" ... generally you see this scroll along.  It keeps me pacified knowing it's not "hung".

Other options include:
1) checking the logs for errors.
2) making sure sitecore didn't reset (sometimes when packages include DLL's, this can cause Sitecore to reset the worker process which might interrupt the package install process.