# While Installing Sitecore Active Commerce-SC80 3.2, I get an error "Unable to load one or more requested types"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Following is stack trace:

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +118
   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly) +172

[ConfigurationException: Failed to load types Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Ecommerce.Apps, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly) +753
   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader.<Load>b__0(String assemblyName) +94
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +102
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 func) +116
   Glass.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader.Load() +272
   Glass.Mapper.Context.<Load>b__0(IConfigurationLoader loader) +63
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +102
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 func) +287
   Glass.Mapper.Context.Load(IConfigurationLoader[] loaders) +425
   ActiveCommerce.Web.App_Start.GlassMapperSc.Start() +60

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +260
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +34
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +288
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +785
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPostStartMethods() +48
   WebActivatorEx.StartMethodCallingModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +155
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +125
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +731
```

Comment: I have got installation guide, which says to make some change in web.config file but that after installation of active commerce.I have installed Sitecore E-Commerce Services 2.2  and Sitecore E-Commerce Order Manager 2.2.Need Help, I am new with Sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sitecore.Ecommerce.Apps.dll` is provided by the SES Order Manager. This error would indicate that the Order Manager package either has not been installed or did not install successfully. I would check if this assembly is in your `bin`, and attempt to install the Order Manager again. After attempting to install, check your Sitecore log to see if there were any errors during installation.

Comment: This dll is not there in bin folder. And I got Order manager package was successfully installed message as well as restart server option(it was checked by default after finishing installing).

Comment: Anything in the Sitecore logs? You should confirm you have the correct version of the order manager. If that file is not in the /bin folder, it is most definitely not being installed successfully.

Comment: ,I have correct version of Order Manager i.e 2.2 , I have tried to install it several times and each time I get message as  Package installed sucessfully. Still I don't see Sitecore.Ecommerce.Apps.dll in bin folder. I don't get anything leading from logs. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Do any of the other package contents appear to install? You can open the package in 7zip and see the files and items that it contains.

Comment: I was able to install it after several attempts, you was right first two packages(ie earlier SES and order manager was not getting installed properly).